# FlipClock - Multiple instances - Counting to specific date in data-countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown, countdowntimer, flipclock

I'm trying to make FlipClock JS countdown to date that is specified in this markup:

```
<script>
    (jQuery)(document).ready(function() {
        clocks.push((jQuery)('.clock-1').FlipClock(3600, {
            countdown: true,
            clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
        }));
    });
</script> 

<div class="clock-1" data-countdown="15/07/2015 17:12:20" style="margin:2em;"></div>
<div class="message"></div>
<div class="clock-1" data-countdown="15/07/2015 23:19:35" style="margin:2em;"></div>
<div class="message"></div>
<div class="clock-1" data-countdown="16/07/2015 19:18:27" style="margin:2em;"></div>
<div class="message"></div>
<div class="clock-1" data-countdown="21/07/2015 16:47:40" style="margin:2em;"></div>
<div class="message"></div>
<div class="clock-1" data-countdown="21/07/2015 22:12:44" style="margin:2em;"></div>
<div class="message"></div>
```

As in using the date + time from

```
data-countdown="21/07/2015 22:12:44"
```

As well as to do it in multiple instances on same page (for example 8 different countdowns per page)

And my other question is if this wont eat to much resources by putting 8 of those countdowns on a page?

Here is my JSFiddle example

CLEAN: https://jsfiddle.net/jx0mmvLq/ (but the script doesnt work at all now, because it seems like I cannot import the FlipClock JS library)

DIRTY: https://jsfiddle.net/haj070g3/1/ (had to add entire library in the "script" section couldnt make it load it in any other way)

I was asked to post links to Docs (but I can only post 2 links with my current rep)

```
http://flipclockjs.com/
```

Comment: The code in your JSFiddle is a mess, too hard to read. Maybe you can clean it up?

Comment: I cleaned it up, but the jsfiddle doesnt want to load the FlipClockJS library for some strange reason and the CLEAN version doesnt really work, in DIRTY version I cleaned up the html which was all I could do without breaking it

Comment: The reason that FlipClockJS cannot be loaded is because you need to have it served via HTTPS.

Comment: What does the class "clock-1" look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first of all, let's change your format of date: `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` to `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss`.

Now your HTML code looks like:

```
<div class="clock-1" data-countdown="2015/07/15 17:12:20" style="margin:2em;"></div>
<div class="message"></div>
<div class="clock-1" data-countdown="2015/07/15 23:19:35" style="margin:2em;"></div>
<div class="message"></div>
<div class="clock-1" data-countdown="2015/07/16 19:18:27" style="margin:2em;"></div>
<div class="message"></div>
<div class="clock-1" data-countdown="2015/07/21 16:47:40" style="margin:2em;"></div>
<div class="message"></div>
<div class="clock-1" data-countdown="2015/07/21 22:12:44" style="margin:2em;"></div>
<div class="message"></div>
```

I see that the plugin doesn't provide the feature when you can apply the plugin to many elements. So let's do that. You need to use `$.each` and apply for each element this plugin.

Also, you need to convert your date to timestamp. JavaScript provides `Date` object: `new Date('yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss').getTime()`. But it gives us milliseconds since 1970/01/01 00:00:00. Not a problem just divide by 1000.

One more thing you need. When you get seconds, you get it since 1970/01/01, but you want to get second by a current date in the future. So, you just get current time and subtract it from the future date.

So all those actions look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clocks = [];

    $('.clock-1').each(function() {
        var clock = $(this),
            date = (new Date(clock.data('countdown')).getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000;

        clock.FlipClock(date, {
            clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
            countdown: true
        });

        clocks.push(clock);
    });
});
```

Well, in hopes it'll help you.

And your last question, I think it's going to work well.

Comment: Thank you for you answer it works great :) not sure about the resource eat up, this vs single counter but I'm supper happy so huge thanks

Comment: @KarolKierzkowski it really depends on a user's hardware. I don't think that 5 counters will eat up so much.

Comment: I have a question maybe you could help me out with this, how could I modify your code in order to add a class if the number is lower then 60 minutes, or if the amount is greater or equal to 100 ?

Comment: I didn't really undestand what you meant. What is the number? data-countdown?

Comment: Thanks for reply! it is count down timer that counts the date down in hours, and I wonder if I can set it up so that based on "amount of hours left" it would add different class to the .clock-1 for example

Comment: the `date` variable stores "amount of hours left" in seconds. you can check it like - `if (date <= 3600) { clock.addClass('someclass'); }`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop through all the `.clock-1` elements, and initialize them one by one. Like this:

```
  (jQuery)('.clock-1').each(function(){

    var clock = (jQuery)(this).FlipClock(3600, {
        countdown: true,
        clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
    });

    clocks.push(clock);

  });
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/haj070g3/2/

As for your question on resource usage, you can just check the Windows Task Manager while your page is open, and determine if it is using too much CPU or not.

**Update:**

To support getting the time from data attribute:

```
  (jQuery)('.clock-1').each(function(){

    var time = (jQuery)(this).data("countdown");
    time = ((new Date(time))-(new Date().getTime()))/1000;

    var clock = (jQuery)(this).FlipClock(time, {
        countdown: true,
        clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
    });

    clocks.push(clock);

  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/haj070g3/4/

Note the date format is in `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS`

Comment: thats nice solution! but only solves half of the problem instead of taking the time from: 

FlipClock(3600, 

it should take the "end date" from

 data-countdown="21/07/2015 22:12:44"

which is part of: 
<div class="clock-1" data-countdown="15/07/2015 17:12:20" style="margin:2em;"></div>
<div class="message"></div>

Comment: I see, I missed that part of the question. I've updated my answer now. Note that you need to change the date format so it can be parsed by JavaScript.

Comment: @alan0xd7 dude, did you just copy my solution? In this case, you can also copy my explanation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, if you check the time on my answer, you can see I posted before you.

Comment: @alan0xd7 oh yeah, your first answer http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31355967/1

Comment: Yes, initially I missed the data part of the question, Karol pointed it out, so I went back and updated it.

Comment: @alan0xd7 thank you for your quick response and help, you provided answer as good as Slimmi and I'm glad you respected the use of (jQuery) instead of $ :) Drupal for some strange reason really dislike $ in JS. I decided to award the answer to the Slimmi as he was the one who provided full solution first - Thanks for your both brilliant input!

Comment: if you add `var $ = jQuery;` to the top of your JS file, then you should be able to use `$` normally.